# Laravel 4 PHP: Using pagination to limit database results

Tags: php, laravel-4

I've read the documentation on how to paginate results from within your database but I'm still very confused on where to put the 'pagination' code within my application.  I want to go with the 'Paginating an Eloquent Model' approach since those are the types of models I'm using.  I'm not sure where to put the 'paginate()' methods.

Should I build a custom controller that:

EDIT:

- Retrieves all the database results from the 'third-party' controller (GalleryController.php)
- Paginates the results in a function within my custom controller such as:

**paginate_albums_Controller.php (Controller)**

```
use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Controllers\GalleryController; // Path of third-party controller

use JeroenG\LaravelPhotoGallery\Controllers\AlbumsController;  // Path of third-party controller

    public function paginate_results($id)
    {                         
         $allAlbums = $this->album->paginate(15);
    }
```

**index.blade.php (View):**

```
 <div class="container">
       <?php foreach($albums as $album); ?>
       <?php echo $album->album_name;  ?>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>

 <?php echo $albums->links(); ?>
```

EDIT: If I use the structure above, could I use that custom controller and use it to call the 'index()' method from the third-party controller **GalleryController.php** that **index.blade.php** uses?

```
 **GalleryController.php (Controller that index.blade.php currently uses):**

 class GalleryController extends BaseController {

/*
 * The album model
 **/

protected $album;

/*
 * The photo model
 */

protected $photo;

/*
 * Instantiate the controller
*/

public function __construct()
{
    $this->album = \App::make('Repositories\AlbumRepository');
    $this->photo = \App::make('Repositories\PhotoRepository');
}

/*
 * Listing all albums
 */

public function index()
 {
    $allAlbums = $this->album->all();
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('gallery::index', array('allAlbums' => $allAlbums));

   /* Is it possible to add code here that will access my custom controller 'paginate_albums_Controller' to paginate the number of albums???? */

 }


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated since I'm still new to using Laravel PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that adding paginate to your index method in class GalleryController will fix this.

```
 public function index()
{
   /*  Change: $allAlbums = $this->album->paginate(15); */
   /*  To: */
   $allAlbums = Album::paginate(15);  
   $this->layout->content = \View::make('gallery::index', array('allAlbums' => $allAlbums));
}
```

Comment: I've actually tried that but it doesn't work since I think 'paginate()' is part of Laravels ORM query and cannot be performed on returned results.

Answer (score 2):

Though this may not be advocated, you can still check out ->all() function of album. Modify the code in the third party and add paginate() there.

paginate() function works on query result. If album->all() modifies the query result in one way or another, paginate() function may not work for it. If you are not comfortable in altering third party code, you may need to write your own code to paginate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get pagination working:

- Took the third-party controller and made it local by changing my 'routes.php' file.
- Edited the controller so that the index function looks like the following:

**Controller:**

```
/* Add the layout file to a folder named 'layouts' in your app/views path 
  This will prevent a 'Creating a default object from empty value reference' from occurring */
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

public function index()
{
    $allAlbums = Album::paginate(10);
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('gallery::index', array('allAlbums' => $allAlbums));
}
```

Edited the view in 'index.blade.php':

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @if ($allAlbums->count())
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    @foreach($allAlbums as $album)
    /* Database column code goes here */
    @endforeach

    {{ $allAlbums-> links()}} // Added this code for the pagination links to actually appear
    </dl>
</div>
```

Pagination works fine now!  Hope this gives a simple explanation on how to use simple pagination in Laravel 4 PHP.